# In Kotlin, does changing internal classes break ABI?

Tags: kotlin

In the Kotlin programming language, let's say there is a module structure with classes like below

```kotlin
/// module A 
   public interface Hello {
      fun doSomething()
   }

   internal class HelloImpl {
       override fun doSomething(){}
   }
// end module A



// Module B--depends on---> Module A

import Hello

class HelloConsumer(private val hello: Hello) {
    fun useDoSomething() {
        hello.doSomething();
    }
}
```

My question is does making changes to the `HellImpl` 's `doSomething` function break the ABI for the module A, and therefore invalidate teh module B and have it recompile/build again?

Answer (score 1):

(I assume `HelloImpl` implements `Hello`)

No, it doesn't break ABI, it is safe to do.

I'm not sure what sources to provide to proof this claim, but this is one of the main reasons why we split the code into public interfaces and private/internal implementations. Module B does not really know about the `HelloImpl`, it does not reference it. In practice, it uses `HelloImpl`, but it doesn't know about it. `Hello` is the only type it "sees".

We can verify this by decompiling `HelloConsumer`. If using decompiler provided in IntelliJ (I believe this is the `FernFlower` decompiler) we receive the following code:

```java
public final class HelloConsumer {
   private final Hello hello;

   public final void useDoSomething() {
      this.hello.doSomething();
   }

   public HelloConsumer(@NotNull Hello hello) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(hello, "hello");
      super();
      this.hello = hello;
   }
}
```

As we can see, `HelloConsumer` uses `Hello` type only, it doesn't reference `HelloImpl` in any way.